# How to forward fillna by using time index

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series, nan

I am trying to count cumulative transactions type(ex) B,W,S,R,D ..) count for each transaction, using groupby Id & tradeType in past 1 hour by using time index.

I used groupby(['Id', 'tradeType']) and rolling('60T') for counting each type of cumulative trade for each transaction in an hour.

### DataFrame

```
index               Id  tradeType  
timestamp           
2018-07-17 16:59:57 1   D     
2018-07-17 17:30:31 1   W     
2018-07-16 15:18:18 2   B     
2018-07-16 15:20:19 2   S     
2018-07-16 15:21:37 2   B     
2018-07-16 15:21:47 2   S    
2018-07-16 15:24:01 2   B    
2018-07-16 15:24:07 2   S    
2018-07-16 15:24:29 2   B    
2018-07-16 15:24:35 2   S     
2018-07-16 15:24:47 2   B     
2018-07-16 15:24:54 2   S    
2018-07-16 15:29:23 2   R     
2018-07-16 15:39:24 2   R     
2018-07-16 15:48:23 2   R     
2018-07-16 16:23:24 2   D     
2018-07-17 12:02:39 2   D    
2018-07-17 12:03:34 2   W    
2018-07-17 12:22:39 2   B    
2018-07-17 12:23:44 2   S
```

```
df['B_count_60T'] = df[df['trade']=='B'].groupby(['Id','tradeType'])['memberId'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('60T').count())
df['S_count_60T'] = df[df['trade']=='S'].groupby(['Id','tradeType'])['memberId'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('60T').count())
df['D_count_60T'] = df[df['trade']=='D'].groupby(['Id','tradeType'])['memberId'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('60T').count())
df['W_count_60T'] = df[df['trade']=='W'].groupby(['Id','tradeType'])['memberId'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('60T').count())
df['R_count_60T'] = df[df['trade']=='R'].groupby(['Id','tradeType'])['memberId'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('60T').count())
```

#### After rolling code

```
                    Id  tradeType   B   S   D   W   R   (_count_60T)
timestamp                           
2018-07-17 16:59:57 1   D           nan nan 1   nan nan
2018-07-17 17:30:31 1   W           nan nan nan 1   nan
2018-07-16 15:18:18 2   B           1   nan nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:20:19 2   S           nan 1   nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:21:37 2   B           2   nan nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:21:47 2   S           nan 2   nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:24:01 2   B           3   nan nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:24:07 2   S           nan 3   nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:24:29 2   B           4   nan nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:24:35 2   S           nan 4   nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:24:47 2   B           5   nan nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:24:54 2   S           nan 5   nan nan nan
2018-07-16 15:29:23 2   R           nan nan nan nan 1
2018-07-16 15:39:24 2   R           nan nan nan nan 2
2018-07-16 15:48:23 2   R           nan nan nan nan 3
2018-07-16 16:23:24 2   D           nan nan 1   nan nan
2018-07-17 12:02:39 2   D           nan nan 1   nan nan
2018-07-17 12:03:34 2   W           nan nan nan 1   nan
2018-07-17 12:22:39 2   B           1   nan nan nan nan
2018-07-17 12:23:44 2   S           nan 1   nan nan nan
```

And then I tried fill nan with right value considering that all value counts are counted by transaction 1 hour. but it was not easily solved.

Is there any good way to make this table by using rolling code?

#### I want to make a table like below

```
                    Id  tradeType   B   S   D   W   R   (_count_60T)
timestamp                           
2018-07-17 16:59:57 1   D           0   0   1   0   0
2018-07-17 17:30:31 1   W           0   0   1   1   0
2018-07-16 15:18:18 2   B           1   0   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:20:19 2   S           1   1   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:21:37 2   B           2   1   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:21:47 2   S           2   2   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:24:01 2   B           3   2   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:24:07 2   S           3   3   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:24:29 2   B           4   3   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:24:35 2   S           4   4   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:24:47 2   B           5   4   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:24:54 2   S           5   5   0   0   0
2018-07-16 15:29:23 2   R           5   5   0   0   1
2018-07-16 15:39:24 2   R           5   5   0   0   2
2018-07-16 15:48:23 2   R           5   5   0   0   3
2018-07-16 16:23:24 2   D           3   3   1   0   3
2018-07-17 12:02:39 2   D           0   0   1   0   0
2018-07-17 12:03:34 2   W           0   0   1   1   0
2018-07-17 12:22:39 2   B           1   0   1   1   0
2018-07-17 12:23:44 2   S           1   1   1   1   0
```

#### Another Try for making this table without using rolling code

It worked, but it took so long time just for making 1 column..

```
df_cnt = pd.DataFrame()

df = df.reset_index()
df['timestamp_before_60T'] = df['timestamp'] - timedelta(hours=1)

for row in df.itertuples():
    col_Id = getattr(row, 'Id')
    col_timestamp = getattr(row, 'timestamp')
    col_timestamp_before_60T = getattr(row, 'timestamp_before_60T')

    tmp = df[(df['memberId']==col_Id)&(df['timestamp']<=col_timestamp)&(df['timestamp']>=col_timestamp_before_60T)]
    tmp_2 = tmp.groupby(['Id']).apply(lambda x: (x['tradeType']=='B').sum())
    df_cnt = pd.concat([df_cnt, tmp_2])
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use `get_dummies` then `groupby` ID and `rolling`:

```
s = (df.join(pd.get_dummies(df["tradeType"]))).sort_index()

print (s.groupby("Id").rolling("60T").sum().drop("Id",1).reset_index())

    Id             level_1    B    D    R    S    W
0    1 2018-07-17 16:59:57  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1    1 2018-07-17 17:30:31  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
2    2 2018-07-16 15:18:18  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3    2 2018-07-16 15:20:19  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
4    2 2018-07-16 15:21:37  2.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
5    2 2018-07-16 15:21:47  2.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
6    2 2018-07-16 15:24:01  3.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0
7    2 2018-07-16 15:24:07  3.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0
8    2 2018-07-16 15:24:29  4.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0
9    2 2018-07-16 15:24:35  4.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
10   2 2018-07-16 15:24:47  5.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
11   2 2018-07-16 15:24:54  5.0  0.0  0.0  5.0  0.0
12   2 2018-07-16 15:29:23  5.0  0.0  1.0  5.0  0.0
13   2 2018-07-16 15:39:24  5.0  0.0  2.0  5.0  0.0
14   2 2018-07-16 15:48:23  5.0  0.0  3.0  5.0  0.0
15   2 2018-07-16 16:23:24  3.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  0.0
16   2 2018-07-17 12:02:39  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
17   2 2018-07-17 12:03:34  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
18   2 2018-07-17 12:22:39  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
19   2 2018-07-17 12:23:44  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Wow.. It worked well! Thank you so much for the solution. I couldn't think that it was solved by this simple way!